# Why does AWS EC2 instance authentication keeps stop working (session maybe)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Problem In Short:** PHP website hosted on AWS EC2 session stops working and restarting the EC2 instance fixes it.

=================

I have this website built on `custom PHP` hosted on `AWS` as an instance of `EC2`, DB is `MySql RDS`. Everything was working just fine a few weeks back. Now at `certain times, the user can't log in` to the website. I reckon there's some problem with the session but not sure.

But `whenever I restart the ec2 instance`, the authentication (user/pass) for the website `starts working again`. This is very strange because.. there's is `no such issues on AWS troubleshooting or in Stackoverflow`. I hope there is a permanent solution rather than having to restart the server every other day.

**This is an `e-commerce site with at least 500 to 700 orders per day`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an issue is resolved by the restart of server/EC2-instance, then most likely you have memory/CPU related problems in your application.

You can do the following to nail the issue

1. Trace the cloudwatch statistics for your EC2 instance for CPU and memory
2. Set up another environment for load testing your application
3. Generate load script to simulate the scenario leading to the problem
4. Run a code profiler to investigate the problematic code
5. Fix problems, run the load again to verify your changes
6. Apply the changes in prod and hope your application rocks in production afterward

**EDIT** : As suggested by @Boinst, as in interm solution you can schedule restart of EC2 instance, while you find the root cause. One of the ways to do that can be to use AWS CLI

```
aws ec2 reboot-instances --instance-ids yourInstanceId
```

you can add a cronjob/scheduled task a machine setup with AWS CLI.

Comment: I agree. #1 is probably a win. Check the *metrics* on your running instance. You will probably see the memory usage going up slowly over time. If that's the case, you've probably got some form of a memory leak somewhere. To buy time while you track down the memory leak, schedule a periodic automated reboot of the server.

Comment: @Boinst, thanks for the suggestion. Can you lead me to a direction on how to  schedule a periodic automated reboot of the server?

Comment: @Geniusintrouble I have edited the answer with Boinst suggestion. I hope you consider this only an interim solution.